# add more than map view in scrollablebiew make crash to my app

Tags: titanium-mobile

**Anyone got any Idea why the app crash when I add 3 map view in scrollabeview ?
How can I do it... and is it a good design?
and is that because the scrollable view talk all mapsview and take from memory so it is crash ... and can anyone give me the way to do that ?!

Comment: If you mean ScrollView, then it can hold only one child view.

Comment: Do you want to implement the Google Map using V1 or  V2 ?

Comment: I use Titanium appcelerator and use Titanium.Map.createView to create Maps ... and use Titanium.UI.createScrollableView to make scrollableview

Answer (score 0):

seems you are using map api v1. FYI till v1 one MapActivity can contain one and only one MapView.most probably your logcat also complaining the same.
 Now in [map api v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) you can embed more then one [MapFragments](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) in your Activity.

Comment: I use Titanium appcelerator and use Titanium.Map.createView to create Maps ... and use Titanium.UI.createScrollableView to make scrollableview

Comment: sorry. no idea about Titanium appcelerator. the day you will write native android code, probably i will be able to help you out:)